# Weblogic Workshop 10.0 very slow

Tags: eclipse, weblogic-10.x

i am working in weblogic 10.0 workshop the problem is that it is very very slow i am using a 4 GB RAM PC (with 3.2GB detected RAM).it is very slow for editing, ctrl+c, ctrl+v consumers a hell lot of time and if its a accidental right click on the editor its goin to eat your time wirthlessly any suggestions to improve ??

Answer (score 1):

Large java applications can often trigger spurious virus scanning activity if you have a virus scanner active.  This can really slow the applications down (I've seen this happen with OWB's designer) and might be the cause of your problem.  If you have an active virus scanner you could try disabling it and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: k will try n update, well dn know while workin in a huge org it ll be possible or not